# В чем смысловая разница: Дорога не видна. -- Дороги не видно?

Tags: семантика, смысл

Какая разница по смыслу:

Дорога не видна. -- Дороги не видно.
Мне хорошо живется. -- Я хорошо живу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Дорога не видна**: дорога где-то здесь, но слишком темно или её что-то заслоняет.

**Дороги не видно**: вероятно, дорога где-то в другом месте.

**Мне хорошо живется**: я доволен жизнью (тем, как она протекает).

**Я хорошо живу**: у меня в жизни всё благополучно (не хуже, чем у других) и средств хватает.

Answer (score 4):

1) **Дорога не видна:** дорога существует, но она скрыта (или ее нельзя увидеть полностью).

Пусть не видна дорога, тем интересней жить. Как на гору ни взбирайся – вся дорога не видна.

**Дороги не видно:** неизвестно, есть ли она вообще поблизости или просто скрыта от глаз.

Дорога окутана туманом и просто невозможно ехать. Дороги вообще не видно.

Заблудилась – не видно дороги.

2) **Мне хорошо живется.** Это внутреннее комфортное ощущение.

Мне хорошо живётся на Руси. Я для себя другой страны не знаю.

**Я хорошо живу**. Это ощущение связано с наличием каких-либо ценностей.

Я живу хорошо.
Лучше день ото дня.
И деньжата лежат
     В сундуке у меня.

Моя хата прочна.
Мне тепло у огня,
И богата еда
     На столе у меня.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:

Смысл одинаковый.

Comment: Что ж, здешние ответы мне нравятся больше :)

Comment: И ответ от первого лица не идёт в сравнение со списанным.