# Есть ли смысловая разница: Музыка не слышна — Музыки не слышно — Музыку не слышно?

Tags: семантика, смысл

Какая разница по смыслу:

*Музыка не слышна.*

*Музыки не слышно.*

*Музыку не слышно.*

Comment: Что-то повторяются вопросы. Это не домашнее задание? Здесь не делают домашних заданий. Похожее было в вопросе о дороге, посмотрите там и сориентируйтесь в смысле фраз.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440544/%d0%92-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5

Answer (score 1):

Музыка не слышна - именно музыка, а не голоса; 
Музыки не слышно - какой-либо музыки (из нескольких или определенного стиля);
Музыку не слышно - сколько-нибудь громкости музыки...

Answer (score -1):

Я бы добавл вот что:
Музыки не слышно - более о категории вещей, например,

В его усердиях музыки не слышно

Т.е нет полета, фантазии, порыва.

Музыку не слышно - части чего-то целого, например,
Разнобой голосов такой, что музыку не слышно.